# Use of service providers within controllers in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller, service-provider

As for the title I've googled about two hours searching for a efficient answer and read repeatedly the official documentation, but without any step further, considering I'm relatively new to the framework. The doubt arise while searching for a correct way to share some code between controllers and i stumbled in service providers, so:

1. I've created say a `MyCustomServiceProvider`;
2. I've added it to the `providers` and `aliases` arrays within the `app.php` file;
3. finally I've created a custom helpers class and registered it like:

   ```
   class MyCustomServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       public function boot()
       {
           //
       }

       public function register()
       {
           $this->app->bind('App\Helpers\Commander', function(){

               return new Commander();

           });
       }
   }
   ```

So far, however, if I use that custom class within a controller I necessarily need to add the path to it through the `use` statement:

```
use App\Helpers\Commander;
```

otherwise I get a nice class not found exception and obviously my controller does not his job.
I suspect there's something which escapes to me on service providers! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So far, however, if I use that custom class within a controller I
>   necessarily need to add the path to it through the use statement:
>
> ```
> `use App\Helpers\Commander;`
> ```
>
> otherwise I get a nice class not found
>   exception and obviously my controller does not his job.

Yes, that's how it works. If you don't want to use the full name, you can use a [`Facade`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades) instead.

Create the Facade class like this:

```
class Commander extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'commander'; }
}
```

register the service:

```
$this->app->singleton('commander', function ($app) {
    return new Commander();
});
```

add the alias to your `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
    //...
    'Commander' => Path\To\Facades\Commander::class,
    //...
],
```

and use it like a `Facade`:

```
\Commander::doStuff();
```

---

On why your code still works, even when you remove the bind:

When you type-hint a parameter to a function, and Laravel does not know about the type you want (through binding), Laravel will do its best to create that class for you, if it is possible. So even though you didn't bind the class, Laravel will happily create a instance of that class for you. Where you actually need the binding is when you use *interfaces*. Usually, you'd not type-hint specific classes but a interface. But Laravel *can not* create a instance of an interface and pass it to you, so Laravel needs to know how it can construct a class which implements the interface you need. In this case, you'd bind the class (or the closure which creates the class) to the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! That's the answer I was expecting for and the one which I couldn't find! But what is not really clear is that if I leave the `register` method empty nothing changes, my custom `Commander` class still works if I add its path, so what's the reason of registering the service provider?

Comment: @Vincent added a paragraph